# Custom Array Adapter to Video Fragment into ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-videoview

I'm trying to make a custom Array Adapter to display videos in a list view. From what I understand, the Adapter is meant to go through an array and display it's contents within a predefined layout. I had this working for a standard String Array Adapter but it seems my custom adapter is not even displaying.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments(); 
        int[] vids = args.getIntArray("vids"); //array of video resources
        //will convert items from aray into a list
        ListView story = (ListView) v;
        ListAdapter vid_view = new ListItemAdapter(getActivity(),foods);
        story.setAdapter(vid_view); //seems not to be loading anything

        return v;
    }

    public static list_page newInstance(int[] vids) {
        list_page page = new list_page();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putIntArray("vids", vids);
        page.setArguments(args);

        return page;
    }
```

My Custom Adapter

```
private int[]vid_array;

    public ListItemAdapter(Context context, int[] vids) {
        super(context, R.layout.video_fragment,vids);
        this.vid_array = vids; //sets the array to video resource array
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater vid_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View custom = vid_inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_fragment, parent, false);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) custom.findViewById(R.id.vid_view);
        String pack = getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        Uri video_res = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + pack + "/" + vid_array[pos]);
        System.out.println("Video Resource: "+ vid_array[pos]); //I don't even see this in the console log
        videoView.setVideoURI(video_res);
        videoView.start();
        TextView vidText = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        vidText.setText(vid_array[pos]);

        return custom;
    }
```

I am new to android and I'm not sure where I am messing up with this adapter. How am I supposed to load the video resources into an array to be parsed out by an adapter and put into a list?

Comment: Did u get an answer? I'm having the same problem as yours.